# Check for registered data then insert into another table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, post

I would like to ask u to help me on some php scripts.

I have two tables **Registered_Bus**  table and **Bus_Route table**

so i want to insert the data in a **Bus_Route table** by checking if the Bus is already registered in a Registered_bus table otherwise prompt the user that the bus is not registered.

Below is a PHP code for insert the Bus_route information

```
// Insert data into mysql

$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('$BID', '$Route', '$Driver_Name',
             '$Driver_phone_no', '$Time_in', '$Time_out', '$Date' , '$Comment')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: provide table structure of both tables!

Answer (score 1):

```
$check = "select count('X') as bus_status from Registered_Bus where id_Registered_Bus = '".$BID."'";
$result_check = mysql_query($check);
$row_check = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_check);
if($row_check['bus_status'] == 1){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('$BID', '$Route', '$Driver_Name',
                 '$Driver_phone_no', '$Time_in', '$Time_out', '$Date' , '$Comment')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "not registered";
}
```

Comment: hey vipin thanks for ur answer but  there is this error 

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\StaffBus\Departure_insert.php on line 27

Comment: replace id_Registered_Bus with proper column name which stores bus id